# Remove all docked items from a panel in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I'm new to Sencha ExtJS and trying to figure out how to efficiently remove all docked items from a panel. The official reference mentions the methods `removeAll` (which only removes regular items and seems unfit for my purpose) and `removeDocked` (which removes only one docked item). Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd look into the code of the [`removeAll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/AbstractContainer.html#Ext-container-AbstractContainer-method-removeAll) function you can see it calls the [`remove`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/AbstractContainer.html#Ext-container-AbstractContainer-method-remove) function.
You can create your own `removeAllDocked` function witch will use [`removeDocked`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/DockingContainer.html#Ext-container-DockingContainer-method-removeDocked).

Comment: Exactly, there's no out of the box function for that. What CD.. suggest is the best way. You can use Ext.apply on the prototype of a panel to add the function for all you panels.